# Forcing class methods to be called from ui thread

Tags: android, multithreading, ui-thread

I created a class and I want it's methods to be available to call only from one specific thread, for instance, the ui-thread. 
It's exactly the opposite from what happens in the android networking api... it throws an exception when it is called from the ui-thread.
How can I do that in android?
thanx

Answer (score 1):

Put this code inside your class methods.

```
   if(!"UI thread".equals(Thread.currentThread().getName())){
    throw new IllegalStateException("wrong thread running this class, thread name:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is how MFC works:

An MFC Window class has many methods that DO NOT perform what is expected from them, instead they send or post a message to a queue that the GUI/main thread listens on.

So you need to either use an existing cross thread messaging mechanism or create your own.

Answer (score -3):

Well, you can do it even inside your class.
Just, get the context of caller activity. And in the method, do `context.runOnUIThread()`

Comment: Thanx, but I mean to force the caller to be in the ui-thread, and to throw an exception otherwise...